# How to deploy android project from visual studio to google play console?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-console

I'm really new among the upload to the google play console platform, and want to register Google API Access from Visual Studio for mac, but every time I receive error:

```
    Authorization error
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't follow Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're an application developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Find out more
The content in this section is provided by the application developer and has not been reviewed or confirmed by Google.
If you're the app's developer, make sure these request details follow Google's policies.

     redirect_uri: http://127.0.0.1:58163/authorize/
```

When I try to to put my Client ID and Client Secret code into the window for Register Google API Access:

[image: ScreenShot]

In the console.cloud.google.com on Credential tab I create OAuth client ID Web application to receive Client ID and Client Secret, because when I click on Android App I not receive Client Secret, and only receive Client ID.
So when I enter Client ID and Client Secret codes into the Register Google API Access window I receive error: 400...

I have two fields inside Authorised JavaScript origins and Authorised redirect URIs.. which is empty...

This is my web Application:

[image: Web Application]

This is my Android Application:

[image: Android App]

**Can I get instructions on how to upload the app to google console ? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to your statement, when you created Google API Access, you
   created OAuth client ID Web application.

   Please choose **CREATE CREDENTIALS** -> **OAuth client ID** -> **Desktop app**.
2. The last screenshot you provided may involve your privacy. I hope you can pay attention to it and modify it.